# Inequality with cumulative probability function of binomial distribution

Tags: probability, inequality

> Prove that $F(k; 2k+1, p) > F(k-1; 2k-1, p)$ where $p < 1/2$.

Here $F$ is the cumulative probability function of binomial distribution

Intuitively the inequality is obvious as expected value $((2k+1)p)$ is on the left and $(\text{standard deviation})/((2k+1)p-k)$ is decreasing by law of large numbers.

Comment: _What_ expected value is on the left? I thought the question was about the cumulative probability distribution function, not the expectation, and what is asked to be proven is that the probability of getting $k$ **or fewer** successes in $2k+1$ trials is larger than the probability of getting $k-1$ or fewer successes in $2k-1$ trials.  Also "variance is decreasing"?? Isn't the variance of the form $np(1-p)$ and thus an increasing function of $n$?

Comment: expected value of distribution (np < k) is on the left of k. Yes variance is increasing. I meant that standard deviation increases by sqrt(n) while distance of k from expected value increases by n. I have edited the question to reflect this.